# why i get wrong json format from modal form after jquery request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am new in asp.net mvc and have a modal pop up form for Advanced filter .when i send data from modal form to Jqgrid filtering method, I get wrong json format like below :

```
 [{"name":"YEAR_ABBR","value":"1398_1398"}
 ,{"name":"YEAR_ABBR","value":"1397_1397"}
 ,{"name":"VAHED_ID","value":"909"}]
```

after running the Jquery request :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $("#loaderDiv").show();
            var myformdata =JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON', 
                data: { filters: myformdata , _search: true },
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Contracts_Steps", "Home")',

                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                                        }
            })
        })
    })
```

I think the correct format for json in my subject should be like this:

```
 [{"YEAR_ABBR":"1398_1398"},{"YEAR_ABBR":"1397_1397"},{"VAHED_ID":"909"}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"wrong format"*? Question is too vague

Comment: @charlietfl, I Have edited my question ,please check it again.

Comment: @New_Dev please share the mvc code to understand better